# SignalR not receiving an abstract type

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr

## Background

I have three classes:

- "A" an abstract base class
- "B" a class then extends "A"
- "C" another class that extends "A"

The client receives no events while we are listening for the type A, however when we listen for types B or C I receive half of the events.  What I want is to listen for abstract type A for any event that extends it while maintaining strong typing.

I am unable to find out if this is a limitation of Signalr or if I'm missing something from my implementation.

## Server

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using SignlR.Shared;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignlR.Experiments.Hubs
{
    public class PolyHub : Hub
    {
        // Empty
    }

    public class PolyService
    {
        private readonly IHubContext<PolyHub> _hubContext;

        public PolyService(IHubContext<PolyHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
            Task.Run(Job);
        }

        private async Task Job()
        {
            A example = null;
            while (true)
            {
                example = new B();
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Example", example);
                await Task.Delay(250);
                example = new C();
                await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("Example", example);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## Client

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using SignlR.Shared;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SignlR.Consoles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("https://localhost:44384/poly")
                .Build();

            connection.StartAsync().Wait();

            connection.On<A>("Example", (obj) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Event" + obj.GetType().FullName);
            });

            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    Console.WriteLine(connection.State.ToString());
                }
            });

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```